# XElement and List<T>

Tags: c#, .net, linq-to-xml, xelement

I have a class that has the following properties:

```
public class Author {
  public string FirstName { get; set; }
  public string LastName { get; set; }
}
```

Next, I have a List of Authors like so:

```
List<Author> authors = new List<Author> ();

authors.add(
  new Author { 
    FirstName = "Steven",
    LastName = "King"
  });

authors.add(
  new Author { 
    FirstName = "Homer",
    LastName = ""
  });
```

Now, I am trying to use Linq to XML in order to generate the XML representing my Authors List.

```
new XElement("Authors",
  new XElement("Author", 
    from na in this.Authors
    select new XElement("First", na.First)))
```

The block above does not generate the XML as I expect it to. What I get is:

```
<Authors>
  <Author>
    <First>Steven</First>
    <First>Homer</First>
  </Author>
<Authors>
```

What I want the XML output to look like is:

```
<Authors>
  <Author>
    <First>Steven</First>
    <Last>King</Last>
  </Author>
  <Author>
    <First>Homer</First>
    <Last></Last>
  </Author>
</Authors>
```

Any help on how to get the XML to look as I need it to would be immensely appreciated!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You need to pass the [`IEnumerable<XElement>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9eekhta0.aspx) query as the second parameter, not the "Author" string, like so:

```
// Note the new way to initialize collections in C# 3.0.
List<Author> authors = new List<Author> ()
{
  new Author { FirstName = "Steven", LastName = "King" }),
  new Author { FirstName = "Homer", LastName = "" })
};

// The XML
XElement xml = new XElement("Authors",
    from na in this.Authors
    select new XElement("Author",
        new XElement("First", na.FirstName),
        new XElement("Last", na.LastName)));
```

That will give you the result you need.

Answer (score 2):

I know you're using C#, but this is one time when you should seriously consider adding a VB.NET project to your solution.  XML Literals are perfect for this and make it much easier.

To get the XML from your Author list, you would do this:

```
Function GetAuthorsXML(authors As List(Of Author)) As XElement
    Return <Authors>
               <%= from a in authors _
                   select <Author>
                              <First><%= a.FirstName %></First>
                              <Last><%= a.LastName %></Last>
                          </Author> %>
           </Authors>
End Function
```

Comment: Having an *entirely separate project* just for a little bit of XML magic is excessive, at best.  Unless there's a tremendous amount of XML transformations that have to be done (and of a more complex nature), adding another assembly (unless you want to compile to modules and then weave them together, which is another PITA) is just adding too much overhead in a number of areas.

Comment: Of course, if this was the only bit, that would be excessive. But it's still valuable for a C# developer to know that this exists in .NET. And I've never worked on a system that didn't have several small projects, so adding one to handle XML magic makes sense to me.