# Linq to Entities inside XML Literal Produces "Only Parameterless Constructors are Supported in Linq to Entities"

Tags: vb.net, entity-framework, linq, sitemap

I am trying to create a dynamic XML sitemap for my ASP.NET MVC web application. The pages are structured and predictable based on the data retrieved from the database by an entity framework 6 model. I would like to simply use XML literals to retrieve each item from the database, sort of like what happens [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1127446/3922521).

My statement looks like the following:

```vb
Dim xmlSitemap = <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
                 <urlset xmlns="http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9">
                     <url>
                         <loc>https://example.com</loc>
                     </url>
                     <url>
                         <loc>https://example.com/Home/Contact</loc>
                     </url>
                     <%= From blog in db.Blogs Select <url>
                                                          <loc>https://example.com/BlogPosts/<%= blog.PostId %></loc>
                                                      </url> %>
                </urlset>
```

Running this code results in **System.NotSupportedException:** 'Only parameterless constructors and initializers are supported in LINQ to Entities.'

Modifying the model to include a `Public Sub New()` with no arguments does nothing to remedy this error. Based on my research after trying that, I'm guessing that this has to do with the fact that I am concatenating strings within the Linq query, but I don't know another way. Is there a way to create the sitemap this way, or am I asking too much?

Comment: I'm guessing that at a .NET level, the compiled expression that's generated by that `<url>` tag is too complex to handle within Entity Framework (i.e. in a SQL statement). Try adding `.ToList()` or `.AsEnumerable()` after `db.Blogs` to force the rest of your LINQ statement into a LINQ-to-Objects context.

Comment: @StriplingWarrior, adding `.ToList()` actually did work. I hadn't thought of that. Could you make your comment into a full answer, so I can mark it correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm guessing that at a .NET level, the compiled expression that's generated by that  tag is too complex to handle within Entity Framework (i.e. in a SQL statement). Try adding `.ToList()` or `.AsEnumerable()` after `db.Blogs` to force the rest of your LINQ statement into a LINQ-to-Objects context.

Note: You'll want to make sure you understand what this is doing, and avoid doing `.ToList()` before a `Where` clause, for example, so avoid serious performance penalties.